# Convergence of $L^1$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, limits, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Given that $\Omega$ is bounded and $a_{ij}(u_{k}) \rightarrow a_{ij}(u)$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$, $a_{i0}(u_{k}) \rightarrow a_{i0}(u)$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$, $\frac{\partial u_{k}}{\partial x_{j}} \rightarrow \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}} \text{ in } L^{1}(\Omega)$, $c_{j}(u_{k}) \rightarrow c_{j}(u) \text{ in } L^{1}$ and $c_{o}(u_{k}) \rightarrow c_{o}(u)$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$ for all $i,j =1,...,n$. We also have $v$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_{i}}$ in $L^{p}(\Omega)$. How does it follow that the limit of the integral is the integral of the limit in the attached image below. I might be missing something simple.

[image]

Let me know if any additional info is required.

Comment: This looks like Chapter 2 out of Roubicek. There is a lot of information about the $a_{ij}$ you are omitting.

Comment: Yes it is out of Roubicek. Do you know why this integral converges based on the other information?

Comment: My idea was that since each of the sequences converges in $L^{1}(\Omega)$ it might be sufficient to conclude the convergence of integral just based on that. But like you suggest an additional piece of info might be used.